# Обработка массивов

Tags: java, массивы, applet

Есть файл HTML. В левой части 5 объектов, в правой части их обработка.

1-е задание:

> Во всех элементах массива вставить в поле типа `String` длину строки (с учетом добавленных символов) в качестве первых символов, если длина меньше значения поля типа int, или в качестве последних символов, если длина больше либо равна значению поля типа  int.

Вот написал код реализации:

```
int i, j, lenr, len;
for (i = len = j = 0; i < realSize; i++) // проход по массиву
{
    lenr = (arrElem[i].getStr()).length(); // в lenr записывается длина строки
    if (lenr > i) // если длина строки > своего индекса
    (arrElem[i].getStr()).concat("lenr"); // то записывается длина строки в конец строки
    else lenr.concat("(arrElem[i].getStr())");
}
```

2-е задание:

> Упорядочить элементы массива по убыванию значения поля типа int.

Вот с этим я не разобрался. Как делать это, вообще не представляю.

Comment: @PIPPETS, выкладывайте ваш код, который нужно проверить, здесь.

Comment: Куча классов в одном файле - это уже нехорошо.

И вы, часом, не путаете между собой java-апплеты и javascript?

Comment: там используются апплеты.

Answer (score 1):

Касательно 2го вопроса это обычная сортировка массива. Воспользуйтесь любым алгоритмом, можно даже встроенным в java [Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[], java.util.Comparator)).

```
Arrays.sort(arrElem, new Comparator<Elem>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Elem o1, Elem o2) {
        if (o1.getInt() < o2.getInt()) {
            return 1;
        } 
        else if (o1.getInt() > o2.getInt()) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Ну, естественно, добавьте проверки на null и поменяйте -1 и 1 местами в соответствии с направлением сортировки.

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с Java-7 для сортировки массива по полю лучше воспользоваться [`Integer.compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29):

```
Arrays.sort(arrElem, new Comparator<Elem>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Elem o1, Elem o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.getInt(), o2.getInt());
    }
});
```

А начиная с Java-8 — ссылкой на метод и [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-):

```
Arrays.sort(arrElem, Comparator.comparingInt(Elem::getInt));
```

Answer (score 0):

Код массива из 8й серии:

```
Arrays.sort(arrElem, Comparator.comparingInt(Elem::getInt));
```